# I can't import files from the dashboard in ipython

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

i'm looking at the Ipthon in depth videos. One of the first execises is import files from the dashboard. It's a very simple process, preesing the "click here" to import the file, select the ipython notebook file, and that's it. That's why i'm very frustrated. Every time i do this, the name of the file is on the list for a few seconds (with the upload button), and then disappears, without any error message on the dashboard nor in the terminal. There's is some kind of verbose output so i can see what's happen? I'm using Ipython 0.13.2 on fedora 18

Thanks!

Comment: same problem under ubuntu 13.10 (fresh install)

Answer (score 0):

Until you get a complete answer this might work.  When I was having issues with this (a complete cleanout and reinstall of IPython sorted it for me), I could still import files by using the drag and drop interface.

I am on Win7 64 so different OS

Comment: No, it didn't work, i use the yum tool to remove the packet and reinstall it, and fails again. I'm going to try installing from the sources